Setting setIsFirstSubsequentAuth, setOriginalAuthAmount and setOriginalNetworkTransId using Authorize.net PHP SDK
I'm using Authorize.net PHP SDK for subscriptions management platform and trying to set setIsFirstSubsequentAuth, setOriginalAuthAmount and setOriginalNetworkTransId during transaction creation process. SDK documentation as always completely unuseful. Does anybody have experience with it?

What problems are you getting with each of these functions? Are they failing with exceptions? Are you just unable to verify that they succeeded?
